# How to create a Matcher instance in CKEditor5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm trying to find an element in the model based on his id.
Looking through the documentation, it seems that the [Matcher](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_matcher-Matcher.html) class can do what I need.

However, I'm unable to create a Matcher instance, and all the examples there show only how to use Matcher, and not how to create the instance.

Sorry if it is a dumb question, but how do I create a new Matcher instance?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to operate over a model, then you should use classes related to `engine/model`. Mentioned by you `Matcher` belongs to `engine/view` so it doesn't fit to model operation.

If you want walk through model and operate over it, then you can use [TreeWalker](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_treewalker-TreeWalker.html) class. You just need to create range over entire model, or create start position at the beginning.

Another option could be obtaining [root element](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#function-getRoot) and iterate over its [children](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_rootelement-RootElement.html#function-getChildren) recursively.

You can utilize tree walker for example in such way:

```
const txt = ( editor => {
    const position = new Position( editor.model.document.getRoot(), [ 0 ] );
    const walker = new TreeWalker( { startPosition: position } );

    for ( const element of walker ) {
        // do sth with 'element'
        // but be careful on element boundaries
    }

    return outputText;
} )( this.editor );
```

You can recursive walking over children here, where `rootElement` can be used as an entry element.

```
function getAllTextFromElementAndChildren( element ) {
    if( element.is( 'text' ) ){
        return elemen.data;
    }

    let text = '';

    for ( const child of element.getChildren() ) {
        const childText = getAllTextFromElementAndChildren( child );

        text += childText;
    }

    return text;
}
```